# dat.GUI - How to link (coordinate, synchronize) 2 (or more) controllers?

Tags: dat.gui

Could anyone explain how to link (coordinate, synchronize) 2 (or more) controllers in dat.gui in general?

Here is an exemple from the official site of dat.gui (https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#2--Constraining-Input)

In this exemple, I'd like to link controller "growthSpeed" and "speed".
The number of "growthSpeed" remains stacked in 0.2 when I choose "Fast"... It must be changed to 5!
(And vice versa... if I change the number in "growthSpeed", it must deselect "Fast"...)

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you set controller GrowthSpeed to .listen() it will update as soon as that variable is changed.  So if the callback for the dropdown changes the variable that growthSpeed is listening to, it will update automatically.